# 2 Independent, 1 Dependent Analysis through SAS. Should I create a surface?

Tags: statistical-significance, sas, matrix, computational-statistics

I have 12 runs of thermal data that each generate a matrix. I've added noise to my systematic data to simulate my detector. My output for each of these is a 500x500 matrix where the vertical axis is my x1, the horizontal my x2, and the data within the matrices are y-values corresponding to a function based on x1 and x2.

I want to find which values are significant and which values are indistinguishable from noise. Where should I start? I was initially thinking of creating a surface with error bars based on the variance of the same points between matrices. This way I can make isopleths based on a change from the noise. (Think topographic map)

What methods in SAS can help me create this?

Example matrix similar to my data, this formula is simply x1*x2=y

```
[1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ]
[2  4  6  8  10 12 14]
[3  6  9  12 15 18 21]
[4  8  12 16 20 24 28]
[5  10 15 20 25 30 35]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For raw visualization, you can use a heat map to visualize the response variable. If you have reason to believe that the data are modeled by a low-degree polynomial, you can use the RSREG procedure, which is for "response surface" regression. The RSREG procedure automatically created contour plots or 3-D surface plots. See the documentation for the PLOTS= option.

For example, here is your example data (converted to long form) plotted with a simple heat map and modeled as a quadratic regression surface.

```
%let numCols = 7;
data M;
input y @@;
x2 = 1 + mod(_N_-1, &numCols); /* col */
x1 = ceil(_N_/&numCols);
datalines;
1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
2  4  6  8  10 12 14
3  6  9  12 15 18 21
4  8  12 16 20 24 28
5  10 15 20 25 30 35
;

proc sgplot data=M;
heatmap x=x2 y=x1 / colorresponse=y;
run;

ods graphics on;
proc rsreg data=M plots=(surface);  /* or surface(3D) */
model y = x1 x2;
run;
```